# Is there a single verb or expression that means "to [gather|aggregate] and then arrange/filter"?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say I am collecting information on a topic 'a' from different sources (1, 2, 3).

Each source may give me one or more pieces of data: 1a, 1a', 2a, 2a', 2a'', 3a.

As I examine this data, I realise that some are more relevant than others, while some are completely irrelevant. I produce a final list of: 3a, 2a', 1a, 1a'.

Is there a single verb or expression that describes this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/compile):

> **to compile** To put together or compose from materials gathered from
>   several sources: compile an
>   encyclopedia.

Answer (score 2):

'collate' may be appropriate.  If you want the sense of dropping irrelevant ones, then 'filter' may be better.